# Navigating calendar by week

Tags: php, datetime, wordpress

I started actually learning a little programming last year, as opposed to just hacking away at libraries and found fragments.

For a WordPress plugin I needed to navigate through weeks, which I thought would be pretty easy. Well it should have been, but my method of using the week and the year returned by php based on timestamp got *interesting*, when navigating back and forth across years around this time of year.

What I ended up with was an obvious mess, but seemed to work... until today.

For your amusement I thought I would share the original code, as well as the refactored code, out of which I created a little [WordPress plugin](https://github.com/MikeiLL/nav_games) in case it's useful for anyone else developing a WP plugin that requires date navigation.

The original mess:

```
function mz_mbo_schedule_nav($mz_get_variables)
{
    $sched_nav = '';
    $mz_schedule_page = get_permalink();
    //sanitize input
    //set week number based on php date or passed parameter from $_GET
    $mz_weeknumber = empty($mz_get_variables['mz_week']) ? date_i18n("W", strtotime(date_i18n('Y-m-d'))) : mz_validate_weeknum($mz_get_variables['mz_week']);
    //Navigate through the weeks
    $mz_nav_weeks_text_prev = __('Previous Week');
    $mz_nav_weeks_text_current = __('Current Week');
    $mz_nav_weeks_text_following = __('Following Week');
    $mz_current_year = strftime('%G', strtotime(date_i18n('Y-m-d'))); 
    $num_weeks_in_year =  mz_weeknumber($mz_current_year, 12, 31);
    if (($mz_weeknumber < $num_weeks_in_year) && empty($mz_get_variables['mz_next_yr']))
    {
        if ($mz_weeknumber == 01)
        {//if we are in first week of year
            $mz_num_weeks_back = add_query_arg(array('mz_week' => ($num_weeks_in_year - 1)));
            }else{
        $mz_num_weeks_back = add_query_arg(array('mz_week' => ($mz_weeknumber - 1)));
        }
        $mz_num_weeks_forward = add_query_arg(array('mz_week' => ($mz_weeknumber + 1)));
        $sched_nav .= ' <a href='.$mz_num_weeks_back.'>'.$mz_nav_weeks_text_prev.'</a>';
        $sched_nav .= ' - <a href='.$mz_schedule_page.'>'.$mz_nav_weeks_text_current.'</a> - ';
        $sched_nav .= '<a href='.$mz_num_weeks_forward.'>'.$mz_nav_weeks_text_following.'</a>';
        $mz_start_end_date = mz_getStartandEndDate($mz_weeknumber,$mz_current_year);
    }
    else
    {   //BOF following year
        $mz_next_year = isset($mz_get_variables['mz_next_yr']) ? mz_validate_year($mz_get_variables['mz_next_yr']) : "1";
        $mz_weeknumber = ($mz_weeknumber > 40) ? $mz_weeknumber - ($num_weeks_in_year - 1) : $mz_weeknumber;
        $from_the_future_backwards = ($mz_weeknumber == 2) ? $num_weeks_in_year : ($mz_weeknumber - 1);
        $mz_num_weeks_forward = add_query_arg(array('mz_week' => ($mz_weeknumber + 1), 'mz_next_yr' => ($mz_current_year + 1)));
        if ($mz_weeknumber == 01)
        {//if we are in first week of year
            $mz_num_weeks_back = add_query_arg(array('mz_week' => ($num_weeks_in_year - 1)));
            $sched_nav .= ' <a href='.$mz_num_weeks_back.'>'.$mz_nav_weeks_text_prev.'</a>';
        }
        else
        {
$mz_num_weeks_back = add_query_arg(array('mz_week' => ($mz_weeknumber - 1), 'mz_next_yr' => ($mz_current_year + 1)));
            $sched_nav .= ' <a href='.$mz_num_weeks_back.'>'.$mz_nav_weeks_text_prev.'</a>';
        }
        $sched_nav .= ' - <a href='.$mz_schedule_page.'>'.$mz_nav_weeks_text_current.'</a> - ';
        $sched_nav .= '<a href='.$mz_num_weeks_forward.'>'.$mz_nav_weeks_text_following.'</a> ';
        $mz_start_end_date = mz_getStartandEndDate($mz_weeknumber,($mz_current_year +1));
    }//EOF Following Year

    $mz_timeframe = array('StartDateTime'=>$mz_start_end_date[0], 'EndDateTime'=>$mz_start_end_date[1], 'SchedNav'=>$sched_nav);

    return $mz_timeframe;
}
```

I didn't bother to include the auxiliary functions, which are mostly unnecessary now.

Here's the refactored code, just sending date back and forth:

```
function mz_mbo_schedule_nav($mz_get_variables)
{
    $sched_nav = '';
    $mz_schedule_page = get_permalink();
    //sanitize input
    //set week number based on php date or passed parameter from $_GET
    $mz_date = empty($mz_get_variables['mz_date']) ? date_i18n('Y-m-d') : mz_validate_date($mz_get_variables['mz_date']);
    //Navigate through the weeks
    $mz_start_end_date = mz_getNavDates($mz_date);
    $mz_nav_weeks_text_prev = __('Previous Week');
    $mz_nav_weeks_text_current = __('Current Week');
    $mz_nav_weeks_text_following = __('Following Week');
    $sched_nav .= ' <a href='.add_query_arg(array('mz_date' => ($mz_start_end_date[3]))).'>'.$mz_nav_weeks_text_prev.'</a>';
    $sched_nav .= ' - <a href='.$mz_schedule_page.'>'.$mz_nav_weeks_text_current.'</a> - ';
    $sched_nav .= '<a href='.add_query_arg(array('mz_date' => ($mz_start_end_date[2]))).'>'.$mz_nav_weeks_text_following.'</a>';

    $mz_timeframe = array('StartDateTime'=>$mz_start_end_date[0], 'EndDateTime'=>$mz_start_end_date[1], 'SchedNav'=>$sched_nav);

    return $mz_timeframe;
}
```

And the auxiliary functions:

```
function mz_getNavDates($date) {
    /*Gets a YYYY-mm-dd date and returns an array of four dates:
        start of requested week
        end of requested week 
        following week start date
        previous week start date
    adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186431/calculating-days-of-week-given-a-week-number
    */
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $date);

    // Get the weekday of the given date
    $wkday = date('l',mktime('0','0','0', $month, $day, $year));

    switch($wkday) {
        case 'Monday': $numDaysToMon = 7; break;
        case 'Tuesday': $numDaysToMon = 1; break;
        case 'Wednesday': $numDaysToMon = 2; break;
        case 'Thursday': $numDaysToMon = 3; break;
        case 'Friday': $numDaysToMon = 4; break;
        case 'Saturday': $numDaysToMon = 5; break;
        case 'Sunday': $numDaysToMon = 6; break;   
    }

    // Timestamp of the monday for that week
    $monday = mktime('0','0','0', $month, $day, $year);
    $seconds_in_a_day = 86400;
    $return[0] = date('Y-m-d',$monday);// requested week
    $return[1] = date('Y-m-d',$monday+($seconds_in_a_day*$numDaysToMon));// end of requested week
    $return[2] = date('Y-m-d',$monday+($seconds_in_a_day*($numDaysToMon))); // following week
    $return[3] = date('Y-m-d',$monday+($seconds_in_a_day*($numDaysToMon - ($numDaysToMon+7)))); // previous week
    return $return;
}

function mz_validate_date( $string ) {
    if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/',$string))
    {
        return $string;
    }
    else
    {
        return "mz_validate_weeknum error";
    }
}
```

Of course input on possible improvements on the new code are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The above navigation wasn't quite right and needed some correction:

```
function mz_getNavDates($date) {
    /*Gets a YYYY-mm-dd date and returns an array of four dates:
        start of requested week
        end of requested week 
        following week start date
        previous week start date
    adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186431/calculating-days-of-week-given-a-week-number
    */
    list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $date);

    // Get the weekday of the given date
    $wkday = date('l',mktime('0','0','0', $month, $day, $year));

    switch($wkday) {
        case 'Monday': $numDaysFromMon = 0; break;
        case 'Tuesday': $numDaysFromMon = 1; break;
        case 'Wednesday': $numDaysFromMon = 2; break;
        case 'Thursday': $numDaysFromMon = 3; break;
        case 'Friday': $numDaysFromMon = 4; break;
        case 'Saturday': $numDaysFromMon = 5; break;
        case 'Sunday': $numDaysFromMon = 6; break;   
    }

    // Timestamp of the monday for that week
    $seconds_in_a_day = 86400;

    $monday = mktime('0','0','0', $month, $day-$numDaysFromMon, $year);
    $today = mktime('0','0','0', $month, $day, $year);
    $weeksEnd = $today+($seconds_in_a_day*(7 - $numDaysFromMon));
    $previousWeek = $monday+($seconds_in_a_day*($numDaysFromMon - ($numDaysFromMon+7)));

    $return[0] = date('Y-m-d',$today);
    $return[1] = date('Y-m-d',$weeksEnd-1);
    $return[2] = date('Y-m-d',$weeksEnd+1); 
    $return[3] = date('Y-m-d',$previousWeek); 
    return $return;
}
```